# How can I get my textbox value instead of defaultValue?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, .net

I have a .net textbox here, and it gets the data from my SQL database.
This is my Textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Tb_Height" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here are my codes behind.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dt = SQLDB.getData(Selcmd, SQLDB.GetConnectyion(), dic);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {  
Selcmd = @"
UPDATE Database59
SET [Height] = @Height 
";}

dic.Add("@Height", Tb_Height.Text.Trim());
SQLDB.exeData(Selcmd, SQLDB.GetConnection(), dic);
```

When my textbox is blank, I text the height 160.
After refresh, the textbox will load the value that is exist in my database
(which is 160)

But when I update the value to 188, it won't change.
I find out that in the front console, it can catch the value 188.
But it always have a "defaultValue 160".
How can I solve it?

Comment: `$("Tb_Height").Value` for jQuery or `Tb_Height.Text` for `.aspx.cs` code-behind

Comment: On Pageload
`Tb_Height.Text = dr["Height"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : (String)dr["Height"];`

$("Tb_Height").Value for jQuery
`$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Tb_Height").val()
"188"`